# Typescript to update Mongodb

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

Got thrown into a Typescript/Mongodb project and am having some trouble getting started. I've been asked to convert data from

```
{

  "_id": {

    "$oid": "636c0a8dce0eb36dc13e63b3"

  },

  "status": "active",

  "companies": [

    {

      "$oid": "5f64bd6785fad3e83771bb4f"

    }

  ],

  "whitelists": [],

  "taxonomies": [

    {

      "$oid": "6080538565c2036dbeadcdfa"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538765c2036dbeadce07"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538d65c2036dbeadce44"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538d65c2036dbeadce46"

    }

  ],

  "itemType": "unit",

  "attributes": [
    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db4"

      },

      "type": "ingredients:statement",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "ingredients:statement#0",

      "value": {

        "footnotes": [],

        "statement": "ingredients: water, butter, lemon juice, wheat flour, egg yolks, sea salt, xanthan gum, turmeric, carotenes."

      }

    },

    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db5"

      },

      "type": "allergens",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "allergens#0",

      "value": {

        "type": "contains",

        "statement": "contains something"

      }

    },

    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db5"

      },

      "type": "allergens",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "allergens#0",

      "value": {

        "type": "something",

        "statement": "may contain something"

      }

    },

    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db6"

      },

      "type": "variants:flavors:raw",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "variants:flavors:raw#0",

      "value": [

        "hollandaise sauce"

      ]

    }

  ],

  "dataUpdatedDate": {

    "$date": {

      "$numberLong": "1668025007811"

    }

  }
}
```

To something like this, merging objects with the same "type" "b"

```
{

  "_id": {

    "$oid": "636c0a8dce0eb36dc13e63b3"

  },

  "status": "active",

  "companies": [

    {

      "$oid": "5f64bd6785fad3e83771bb4f"

    }

  ],

  "whitelists": [],

  "taxonomies": [

    {

      "$oid": "6080538565c2036dbeadcdfa"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538765c2036dbeadce07"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538d65c2036dbeadce44"

    },

    {

      "$oid": "6080538d65c2036dbeadce46"

    }

  ],

  "itemType": "unit",

  "attributes": [
    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db4"

      },

      "type": "ingredients:statement",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "ingredients:statement#0",

      "value": {

        "footnotes": [],

        "statement": "ingredients: water, butter, lemon juice, wheat flour, egg yolks, sea salt, xanthan gum, turmeric, carotenes."

      }

    },

    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db5"

      },

      "type": "allergens",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "allergens#0",

      "value": [{

        "type": "contains",

        "statement": "contains something"

      },

      {

        "type": "something",

        "statement": "may contain something"

      }

    ]},

    {

      "_id": {

        "$oid": "6384d2bdf29f40634fe77db6"

      },

      "type": "variants:flavors:raw",

      "key": "0",

      "parent": "nutrition:panel#0",

      "uid": "variants:flavors:raw#0",

      "value": [

        "hollandaise sauce"

      ]

    }

  ],

  "dataUpdatedDate": {

    "$date": {

      "$numberLong": "1668025007811"

    }

  }
}
```

My background is php/mysql. I understand the basics here just can't put it together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I have the basics of the typescript started to grab all the appropriate documents. I don't know how to go about combining some of the data and updating it back to mongo

Here is the basic code I am starting with

```
makeScript({
module,
db: true,
init: async _argv => {
    await Pv2.find({
        attributes: {
            $elemMatch: {
                type: 'allergens'
            },
        },
    })
    .limit(10)
    .cursor()
    .eachAsync(async (oldPv2s: Pv2Doc | Pv2Doc[]) => {
    // not sure what goes here
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Your original document isn't valid JSON, nor BSON.  Is this [mongoplayground.net configuration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YBuy0syuAgQ) accurate for your actual data?

Comment: Hi, please add a minimal working sample of code for your problem. I understand you're having issues with the combining of the data. Are you also having issues "updating it back to mongo"?

Comment: @rickg12hs, zion, I updated the json example and added the typescript. I can compile the list of "allergens" I need. I'm not sure how to remove/update the record in mongodb. I'm not sure my approach is the most efficient. Thanks